# Cannot access a disposed object in a gRPC call from the client

Tags: c#, grpc

I am trying to create a gRPC service with code first.

[This is he documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/code-first?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

My client code is this:

```
public class ClienteGrpcDotNet
    {
        #region constructores
        public ClienteGrpcDotNet()
        {
            using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5206");
            _client = channel.CreateGrpcService<IGreeterService>();
        }
        #endregion constructores



        private IGreeterService _client;



        public async Task<string> SayHelloAsync()
        {
            HelloReply miRespuesta = await _client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });

            return miRespuesta.Message;
        }
    }
```

This is the application that uses the client implementation:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ClienteGrpcDotNet miCliente = new ClienteGrpcDotNet();

            string miStrRespuesta = await miCliente.SayHelloAsync();

            MessageBox.Show(miStrRespuesta);
        }
```

The problem is when I call the SayHelloAync method, in the client implementation, I get the error: Cannot access a disposed object. Is in this line:

```
HelloReply miRespuesta = await _client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
```

This is my service implementation:

```
public class GreeterService : IGreeterService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
        public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }



        #region implementación del servicio
        public Task<Service.Comun.HelloReply> SayHelloAsync(Service.Comun.HelloRequest request, CallContext context = default)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(
                   new Service.Comun.HelloReply
                   {
                       Message = $"Hello {request.Name}"
                   });
        }
        #endregion implementación del servicio
    }
```

But the service doesn't receive the call from the client, the problem is before it.

Why do I get this error?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but the "Cannot access a disposed object." happens when your SayHelloAsync method tries to access the object _client, as if the object is already closed. 
That commonly happens when you try to interact with a object that is already disposed (as a form, e.g.).  I'd try to see that "Task" call that you do.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem is in the constructor ClienteGrpcDotNet(), where I was using using var channel. It was an error because I was copying the code and I didn't realize. I have to delete using because if not, the channel is disposed when the constructor finishes its work.

Comment: Glad to help :)